# iTunes Search API Incorrect values

Tags: app-store, itunes, itunes-store, itunes-search-api

I'm attempting to use the iTunes Search API to get information from the app store. When verifying the data from the App store itself, there seems to be some kind of mismatch. For example with Uber :

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/uber/id368677368

It shows the Average User Rating to be **4.7 out of 5** with **178k ratings**

When using the API URL :
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=uber&entity=software,iPadSoftware&attribute=softwareDeveloper

I'm getting the following data for the results :

AverageOverallRating : **4.5 out of 5** with **229,288 ratings**

AverageRatingForVersion : **4.5 out of 5** with **12,201 ratings**

I even tried modifying the country attribute for the API to be US, just to make sure. I've verified the ID in the API Result matches the ID in the appstore URL.

I can't for the life of me figure out how they're calculating this rating, and why the values don't match. It's not like the API is a third party API, it comes directly from Apple.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure this out? I faced the same problem. I think Lookup API round up the results for some reason.

Comment: Unfortunately no, to this day it's still a mystery. 
I think the API is some legacy system that didn't scale well and they're not really supporting anymore or something. But who knows?